# Google Beacon Not Recognized

Tags: android, beacon, google-beacon-platform

I recently received 2 Beacons from Google for my small business. I followed the installation instructions that came in the box. To activate it, I followed the link  in the box, which brought me to a Google form page to enter in the activation code. I then downloaded the Beacon tools app for Android to start using them. However, when I searched for the Beacons in the app, it said there wasn't any unregistered or registered Beacons in the area. I was standing right under them so proximity isn't the issue. I also waited a day in case they needed time to activate, but they still are not recognized.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Is there something I am missing to register my Beacons? I looked everywhere for a support page on Google's page about their Beacons and this was all that came up. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that one of the following is true:

1. Your hardware beacons are not transmitting as you expect.
2. You Android device is not able to detect the beacons.

To troubleshoot this and find out which of the above is the problem, I suggest you get a second phone (either iOS or Android).  On both phones, install the free "Beacon Locate" app from the Google Play Store or the Apple App Store.  You can use this app to both transmit as a beacon and detect beacons.  Run the app on both phones simultaneously, making one transmit and the other receive.  This will let you verify if your current phone that cannot detect your hardware beacons is capable of detecting any beacons at all.

If you find that your current phone can detect other beacons but not the hardware ones you ordered, then double check the instructions to turn them on and make sure the batteries (if any) are not dead.

If you find that your current phone cannot detect a beacon transmitted by the second phone, then you need to verify that Bluetooth is on, Location is on, and that the phone does not have a hardware problem that prevents bluetooth detection.